# What is a good review book/source for microbiological diagnosis?

Tags: microbiology, book-recommendation

I am trying to find the diagnosis figure for different bacteria where phases are illustrated.

I am using at the moment: 1) [First Aid for the USMLE Step 1 2013](http://www.mhprofessional.com/product.php?isbn=0071802320&cat=116) and 2) [Medical Microbiology by Murray et al, 7e](http://store.elsevier.com/Medical-Microbiology/Patrick-Murray/isbn-9780323086929/).

**What is a good review source for basic microbiological diagnosis?**

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

### Koneman's Color Atlas and Textbook of Diagnostic Microbiology

by Elmer W. Konema